# vim finding all extensions associated with a filetype

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, filetype

How can I find all file extensions that will use specific filetype (highlighting)?

For example I know that both ".xml" and ".xmi" files will by opened as "xml" filetype, however I would like to find what else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run vim

```
 vim
```

Redirect ex commands to the buffer a:

```
:redir @a
```

Print all of auto commands:

```
:au
```

Switch of redirecting:

```
:redir END
```

Paste the buffer a to text

```
"ap
```

Search for all occurrences of the `setf xml`.